# Scale, position, and zoom a still image in Premiere Pro CC

Tags: premiere, scale, zoom

I have a photo collage I am trying to move around, scale, position, and zoom in and out of on the images with in the collage. Whenever I go to scale out of the first image and move to the second image it messes up all of the key frames. Am I missing something while trying to do this?

I am trying to achieve the same effect of the linked video below

Answer (score 1):

That's very easy. Simply select all images, press right click -> Nest.
Give it a name and you are done. Now on this single "clip" apply your movement.
If you want to edit the single images, double click the new clip.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have keyframes, than you need to move all of them, not just first. The easiest way to achieve that. is by nesting your current video with all its keyframes in new composition, and add scale, zoom and etc to it. But only you can see, if this workflow fits your needs.

Alternative way will be, to select all existing keyframes, and modify them... But it can become messy and broke pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this, as far as I can see, is by creating a single image file (in Photoshop or GIMP or something) and then importing that into Premiere - unless, of course, you're animating all of the images in or something - then just moving/scaling on one 'clip' as opposed to trying to move and scale across a lot of different clips.

If you are animating the images in, nesting the video would be the best thing to do (as Shultc suggested) though the terminology in Premiere is a 'subsequence', not a 'composition'. To do this, select all of the clips, right click and go down to 'Make subsequence' - this will create a new sequence in your project that you can drop into your main sequence. Edit the content in the subsequence by loading it (double-click) as you would a normal sequence. Any changes you make will be reflected in the subsequence clip.

If you have After Effects, I'd suggest building this effect in there as it's far more useful for creating effects like this than Premiere is, though the process would be fairly similar, you'd just create a pre-composition with your collage in it, then edit (move/scale) the pre-comp in your main comp.